# How to allow my computer to download .py files from an email

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to download a .py file from an email. I get the error "file not supported." The file was saved from a Jupyter-notebook script.
I have Python 3.6.6 and Jupyter downloaded on my Windows 10 laptop and tried to access the file through Chrome and through my computer's email app, but this didn't resolve the problem.

Any ideas on how to make the file compatible with my computer?

EDIT: I had to have the .ipynb file sent rather than the .py file.

Comment: Email doesn't understand the extension `.py` You need to download the file from the email (assuming .py file is as an attachment in your email). and then open it with an application which supports .py extensions

Answer (score 0):

Generally email providers block any thing which can possibly execute on clients machine.

Best option to share will be transfer via email will be .py.txt

or any cloud drives.